# Mount ftp as removeable drive

Tags: ftp, mount, android, smb

I am trying to achieve wireless Sync to my android device using doubleTwist. With SwiFTP I can connect to my phone wirelessly and using programs like NetDrive, I can mount it to windows 7.

One issue, doubleTwist requires the device to show as removable media, not a local disk. Any ideas?

Comment: I switched from double twist to winamp. Ironically they came out with an android player the day after I asked this question. It supports flac too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the new winamp supports android WIRELESS SYNC!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a page that links to a few utilities that let you mount an FTP source to a network drive letter.
http://smallvoid.com/article/ftp-map-network-drive.html

alternatively you can run an SMB client on your phone, which will let explorer map/browse to it directly without ftp

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/smb%20client